# How do I fetch infohash and torrent metadata from DHT nodes without having knowledge of infohash?

Tags: bittorrent, kademlia

According to this DefCon talk [Crawling BitTorrent DHTs for Fun](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cvQrNoCwxgE), BitTorrent DHT nodes can be crawled to build a torrent site overnight from scratch even if every other torrent site along with their backup is shut down by an adversary.

In kademlia, a peer learns infohash from torrent sites indexing magnet links for each torrent. A peer issues `get_peers` request to fetch the list of peers currently downloading and seeding the torrent. The dht node whose *node ID* is closest to the infohash return metadata to the querying peer.

In anyway I need infohash to query for peers. So how one can build a torrent site overnight if one doesn't have a infohash? The only possible way I think is exhaustive key search. One has to randomly generate `160-bit` infohash and start querying for peers but that would take very long time.

Is there any existing **Remote Procedure Calls** in kademlia like `get_infohash` or `get_metadata` which allows a dht node to query neighbouring nodes for infohash because that's the only way to learn infohash directly from dht nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **DHT Infohash Indexing**. This *BitTorrent Enhancement Proposal* or **BEP** is under consideration for standardization. This extension enables DHT nodes to retrieve a sample of the infohashes that other nodes currently have in their storage.

From the author, [BEP 51](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0051.html)

> DHT indexing already is possible and done in practice by *passively* observing **get_peers** queries. But that approach is inefficient, favoring indexers with lots of unique IP addresses at their disposal. It also incentivizes bad behavior such as spoofing node IDs and attempting to pollute other nodes' routing tables.
>
> With this extension a single node should be able to survey the entire DHT within a few hours without having to resort to non-compliant behavior.
>
> Since it cannot be directly used to search for specific torrents it is not expected that average clients actually use this RPC, they only need to support replying to it. Instead the intended use is that a few specialized indexers in the network use it as building block to create and curate a database of available torrents and then make it available to end users through other means, e.g. as a web service or through torrent feeds.

```
Message Format

Request:

{
    "a":
    {
        "id": <20 byte id of sending node (string)>,
        "target": <20 byte ID for nodes>,
    },
    "t": <transaction-id (string)>,
    "y": "q",
    "q": "sample_infohashes"
}

Response:

{
    "r":
    {
        "id": <20 byte id of sending node (string)>,
        "interval": <the subset refresh interval in seconds (integer)>,
        "nodes": <nodes close to 'target'>,
        "num": <number of infohashes in storage (integer)>,
        "samples": <subset of stored infohashes, N × 20 bytes (string)>
    },
    "t": <transaction-id (string)>,
    "y": "r"
}
```

> As usual, additional fields may be defined by other BEPs.

Comment: FYI, there are very few implementations which implement BEP51. https://github.com/0xcaff/dht-crawler/issues/8

Comment: @0xcaff I hope your implementation is adopted by other torrent clients. [the 8472](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362755/the8472) is the original author of BEP51. I've tried [yours](https://github.com/0xcaff/dht-crawler) and [his](https://github.com/the8472/mldht) implementation of BEP51 to collect info-hashes for decentralised search engine and crawler but the problem is that almost all dht_nodes ignore BEP51 krpc query because no torrent clients are implementing this. In recent years there hasn't been any development in the BitTorrent protocol.